# how to compare ID in Work item query language

Tags: c#, wiql

I am writing a WIQL query where I need to filter out contents based on the ID of a workitem. Here I need to compare the ID with a user defined value and I don't know how to do that.

Below is my code:

```
string queryString = "Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = @Type AND [ID]= ";
```

I have heard about IDictionary implementation but, I don't know how that will help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as adding the value of the ID to the end of the string?

```
string queryString = "Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = @Type AND [ID]= " + myId;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! I am to new WIQL and this simple query was creating a mess for me.....thanks for the quick response, it was a great help for me.....